# Postgres: Update Heavy App Performance same techniques as Reads?

Tags: postgresql, performance, graphql

Do the typical techniques for increasing `SELECT` or read performance in an application help with `UPDATE` performance for Postgres?

1. Indexes
2. Cache (Planning on using Redis)

Open to any other methods for increasing `UPDATE` performances as it seems most optimizations are for Reads (con of reducing write performance).

This is a GraphQL API using Postgres.

Comment: Yes and no. In general, increasing read performance comes with some write overhead (having to update indices and invalidate caches), but `UPDATE` does both reading and writing so it might still be a net gain.

Comment: How would it be a net gain, since updates are considered both reads and writes?

Comment: If you want to update a specific row, it first has to find it - an index definitely can help with that